# Invariance of volume along Ricci flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

The Riemannian metric is $g_{ij}$,its inverse is $g^{ij}$,and the induced measure is $du=u(x)du$ where $u(x)=\sqrt{det(g_{ij})}$.The scalar curvature is $R=g^{ij}R_{ij}$ . $r=\frac{\int R du}{\int du}$ is the average scalar.Consider the equation $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}g_{ij}=\frac{2}{n}rg_{ij}-2R_{ij}$ .
I understand that $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\log u=\frac{1}{2}g^{ij}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g_{ij}=r-R$ . How to show that :

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int du=\int (r-R)du=0
$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @JohnMa I can do nothing,I try to compute the first equation,but fail .

Comment: @JohnMa Do you have some detailed book about Ricci flow?

Comment: There are **a lot** of detailed books on Ricci flow...

Comment: @JohnMa The "a lot" can't be opened .

Comment: Well, if you are in a university, very likely you have all the books you need.  If not, there are indeed a lot of websites that somehow you can find a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_M du = \int_M \frac{\partial}{\partial t} du = \int_M \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x)\right) \,dx^1\cdots dx^n$$

From here you should be able to derive that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_M du = \int_M (r-R) du.$$

That the last term is zero has nothing to do with Ricci flow: For any function $f$, if $A$ is the average of $f$, then

$$\int_M (f-A) du = 0.$$

Comment: So thank you , tomorrow I cost all day to compute it ,but nothing got.